# Authlogic account activation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I have a requirement where the user creates an account through form with name and email. I need to send him an activation link once he clicks on it he must be able to choose a password. I am using authlogic please let me know the best way of achieving it.

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried so far, including some code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Authlogic has very comprehensive guide; you can almost copy and paste everything:
https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic